# How do you replace a set of words with a list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I am a GCSE Computing student who is relatively new to python. I am on my third programming task which involves making a simple hangman game. I have managed to get the game working but part of the success criteria is that the user can change the set of words. At the minute the program is using a list of preset words. I have managed to write the code allowing the user to enter the new sets of words in and these are then stored as a list. However I have had problems when trying to replace the old set of words with the new list entered by the user.
I am incredibly stuck and as I am still on holiday have been unable to ask my teacher for help. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I am running out of time (we are taking the GCSE in June 2013)
Thanks.

```
def newwords():
        newgamewords.append(input('Enter new word: '))
        print('Do you want to add any more words? yes or no?')
        answer=input()
        if answer == 'yes':
            newwords()
        else:
            while len(guessedletters) > 0 : guessedletters.pop()
            while len(displayletters) > 0 : displayletters.pop()
            while len(hangmanpics) > 0 : hangmanpics.pop()
            gamewords[:]=newgamewords
            hangmangame()
```

Here is some of the code...

Comment: You're probably going to need to show your existing code to allow people to understand what you're trying to do and what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the elements in a list (in place) using slice assignment:

```
word_list = [ 'foo','bar','baz' ]
new_list = [ 'qux','tux','lux', 'holy cow!  python is awesome' ]

word_list[:] = new_list
print(word_list)  #[ 'qux','tux','lux', 'holy cow!  python is awesome' ]
```

`new_list` and `old_list` don't even need to be the same length.

---

You can also replace only part of a list with part of the other list if you'd like:

```
word_list = [ 'foo','bar','baz' ]
new_list = [ 'qux','tux','lux', 'holy cow!  python is awesome' ]

word_list[1:-2] = new_list[:-1]
print word_list #['foo', 'qux', 'tux', 'lux', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: def newwords():
        newgamewords.append(input('Enter new word: '))
        print('Do you want to add any more words? yes or no?')
        answer=input()
        if answer == 'yes':
            newwords()
        else:
            while len(guessedletters) > 0 : guessedletters.pop()
            while len(displayletters) > 0 : displayletters.pop()
            while len(hangmanpics) > 0 : hangmanpics.pop()
            gamewords[:]=newgamewords
            hangmangame()

Comment: @user1949690 -- Reading python code in comments is almost impossible.  It's always nice to have some code in the question, you can edit your original post by clicking `edit` and adding the code there.